# Cannot import default with typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

There is this library called 'resize-observer-polyfill' which declares that it has a default export:

```
declare var ResizeObserver: {
  prototype: ResizeObserver;
  new(callback: ResizeObserverCallback): ResizeObserver;
}

export default ResizeObserver;
```

But I cannot import this library because TS complains.

```
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill'

// If I do this instead, TS is happy but ResizeObserver is undefined !!
import * as ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill'
```

TS config extract:

```
, "compilerOptions":
  { "jsx": "react"
  , "module": "commonjs"
  , "noImplicitAny": true
  , "outDir": "output/dist"
  , "reactNamespace": "JSX"
  , "sourceMap": true
  , "strictNullChecks": true
  , "target": "es6"
  }
```

Using **allowSyntheticDefaultImports** makes types and runtime happy but then many imports fail in jest (using ts-jest) unless I set **skipBabel** to true.

Using the `skipBabel` option, this import fails in tests with an undefined value, I have to use the `import * as ResizeObserver` syntax in tests.

What is the proper way to do this ? Why is it such a mess anyway ?

Comment: Try `import {ResizeObserver} from 'resize-observer-polyfill'`

Comment: I believe you must declare a module with the same name as the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the first syntax (`import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill'`) with `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` both set to true in your `tsconfig.json`.  You need the former to allow `import ResizeObserver` instead of `import * as ResizeObserver`, and I think you may need the latter since you're targeting `es6`.

I found the [release notes for TS 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop) very helpful in understanding this.